# Know the running container doing what?

Tags: linux, docker

In my Linux server(CentOS), I have two docker containers running. See the image.

[image: 1]

I know the second one, it is a web application. I can type the url and verify it. But for the first one `84e56f542641`, I have no idea what it is, maybe I created it or somebody did it. I just don't recall it. I want to delete it but I have to ensure the safe action.

Is there a way to figure it what it is?

Answer (score 0):

1. Review the container's running processes from the host or Container itself.

   - From the host

     > Docker top ContainerID
   - From within the Container

     > top
2. Retrieves whatever logs are present for a container at the time of execution.

   > Docker logs

   - `--follow` will first return all the logs from the beginning and then continue to stream new output from the container's stdout and stderr.
3. Shut it down and see if anything screams.